# Cobol storing file to table

Tags: cobol

I'm trying to store a pattern received from text file into a table in COBOL.
I am using READ.. INTO.. statement to do so, and here is what I have so far.

```
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01 ROWCOL.
        03 NROW     PIC 9(3).
        03 NCOL     PIC 9(2).
   01 PATT-INIT.
        03 ROW PIC X OCCURS 1 TO 80 TIMES
              DEPENDING ON NCOL.
   01 PATT.
        03 COL OCCURS 1 TO 80 TIMES
              DEPENDING ON NCOL.
              05 ROW OCCURS 1 TO 100 TIMES
                    DEPENDING ON NROW PIC X.

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   MAIN-PARAGRAPH.
        OPEN INPUT INPUT-FILE.
        READ INPUT-FILE INTO ROWCOL.
        PERFORM READ-PATTERN
        STOP RUN.

   READ-PATTERN.
        READ INPUT-FILE INTO PATT-INIT(1:NCOL).
```

The pattern in the input.txt would look something like this:

```
011000
001010
010100
```

The thing about this is that, I'm not sure how to place the PATT-INIT array into the PATT 2d-array. I'm only using the PATT-INIT array to receive row-by-row the pattern in each line. Then, I'm trying to store it into PATT 2d array such that I can access each number by the index numbers. e.g. PATT(1:2) would return 1.

Please give me some pointers on how to implement this. If READ.. INTO.. is not the way to go, I'm more than happy to receive other suggestions.

Comment: You show six-digit data, the first of which you READ ... INTO ROWCOL, which is five characters. ROWCOL consists of two values you use for Occurs Depending On, which from your data are 11 and zero. For all IO you should check the FILE STATUS to see if you were successful. It is bad practice, to me, to not CLOSE a file, even if, in your circumstance, you can "get away with it". As yet I see no need for ODO. PATT(1:2) would get you "01". What you are trying to do is unclear, to me, please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* part of your problem is that you think things like (1:NCOL) are doing one thing, when in fact they mean something completely different. The notation indicate "reference modification". You probably are expecting ordinary subscripting, or at least "reference modification" from a variable starting point with a fixed length of one.

```
01  a-nicely-name-table.
    05  FILLER OCCURS 80 TIMES.
        10  a-nicely-named-row-entry.
            15  FILLER OCCURS 6 TIMES.
                20  a-nicely-named-column-entry PIC X.
```

The data from your READ goes into a-nicely-name-row-entry ( subscripted ). Once everything is there, you can reference a paricular column on a particula row by  a-nicely-named-column-entry ( a-row-subcript, a-column-subscript ).

Note, without the ":" this is subscripting, not "reference modification". The comma is optional.

You need to ensure that you don't go "outside" the bounds of the number of rows you put in the table, and also that you do not "overflow" the table with input data.

You can use indexes for subscripting (INDEXED BY on the OCCURS definition). I haven't in the example, as it is unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I overlooked the strictness of COBOL. A nice subscript solved the problem!

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your question properly, there may be a couple of problems. Bill an Bruce have noted
that you seem to be mixing up subscript and reference modification. Basically
something like:

```
  DISPLAY PATT-INT (1:3)
```

will display the first 3 characters of `PATT-INT`. This is a reference modification. While

```
  DISPLAY ROW OF PATT (1, 3)
```

will display the character at `COL` 1, `ROW` 3 of the `PATT` table. Notice that you need to reference the "lowest" level element name here so maybe renaming some of your data structures make it a little easier to "follow".

The other problem might be a confusion between rows and columns...

The `input-txt` file you gave has 3 lines of data (rows). Each line has 6 characters (columns). Your
declaration of `PATT-INIT` seems to re-enforce that since it has an `OCCURS NCOL` times. When you read one
line of data you get 6 columns for that row. However, the `PATT`
table flips this on its side. It is declared with a Column then Row layout. 
This layout means you cannot read directly into it from `input.txt` because the table declaration
does not follow the file layout.

Two solutions to that problem.

This is the one I think you might have been trying to work toward:

Read each `input.txt` line and store it in `PATT` such that it
becomes 6 columns in `PATT` for the same row. For example the first row of input: `011000` would be
stored in `PATT (1, 1)` through `PATT (6, 1)`, 6 columns, 1 row. Note: You
indicated that `ROW OF PATT (1, 2)` should have a value of '1' - here `ROW OF PATT (2, 1)` would be '1'.

That aside, you could read one line of input into a single dimension array (`PATT-INIT`) and then 
redistribute it into
the `PATT` table. Here is a program outline:

```
 MAIN-PARAGRAPH.
     OPEN INPUT INPUT-FILE
     READ INPUT-FILE INTO ROWCOL
     PERFORM VARYING WS-R FROM 1 BY 1
               UNTIL WS-R > NROW
        PERFORM READ-1-ROW
     END-PERFORM
     CLOSE INPUT-FILE
     .
 READ-1-ROW.
     READ INPUT-FILE INTO PATT-INIT (1:NCOL)
     PERFORM VARYING WS-C FROM 1 BY 1
               UNTIL WS-C > NCOL
        MOVE ROW OF PATT-INIT (WS-C) TO ROW OF PATT (WS-C, WS-R)
     END-PERFORM
     .
```

The other solution might to be redefine `PATT` as

```
01 PATT.
     03 ROW OCCURS 1 TO 100 TIMES
           DEPENDING ON NROW.
           05 COL OCCURS 1 TO 80 TIMES
                 DEPENDING ON NCOL PIC X.
```

Now you can simply read as follows:

```
 MAIN-PARAGRAPH.
     OPEN INPUT INPUT-FILE
     READ INPUT-FILE INTO ROWCOL
     PERFORM VARYING WS-R FROM 1 BY 1
               UNTIL WS-R > NROW
        READ INPUT-FILE INTO ROW (WS-R) (1:NCOL)
     END-PERFORM
     CLOSE INPUT-FILE
```

You can drop the `PATT-INIT` working storage since it is no longer referenced.

Note: With this layout  `COL OF PATT (1, 2)` = '1'

Flesh out the above with proper data edits, bounds checks and `FILE-STATUS` checking after each I/O to
complete the program.

Comment: I can't see any indication that there is a need to retain the ODOs. They are not being "used" and if subscripts and reference-modification are already being confused, then unnecessary ODOs are just an "accident waiting to happen". At it is, with the ODO on COL, the reference-modification is superfluous, as ROW is NCOL in length already. Unless Hwa Soo Cho returns to say why, I'd drop the ODOs and the reference-modification, as I can't see an actual need for either.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the **read into** it is with **PATT-INIT(1:NCOL)**. This is called
[Reference Modification](http://www.fluffycat.com/COBOL/Reference-Modification/).

Cobol does Line or record orientated IO. so

```
  READ INPUT-FILE INTO PATT-INIT
```

is probably what you want. To access an array element use (i,j) not (i:j)

Comment: And given that PATT-INIT contains an ODO with NCOL, the difference would be? They would both do the same things (making the reference-modification redundant). There is no problem with reading into a reference-modified field per se. Here, there is no data which matches ROWCOL, for the first READ ... INTO ..., but perhaps it is really there. For the READ ... INTO to just put a whole record in, unmodified by NCOL, the ODO on PATT-INIT has to go.

Comment: You are correct, there is no problem writing into a reference modified field. The problem is the reference modification 1:NCol, If he is reading the file one byte at a time, NCol:1 or 1,NCol will work. 1:NCOL will move the input char to the first char and blank fill the next NCOL- characters.

Comment: "I'm only using the PATT-INIT array to receive row-by-row the pattern in each line". I can't see anything there to indicate TS thinks they are reading byte-by-byte. Even if so, as I said, due to the ODO, the READ ... INTO ... that you suggested is *identitcal* to the reference-modification version, so if the reference-modification were the problem, so would be your suggested soluttion.